# Batch scripting: cross browser testing with login

Tags: batch-file, cross-browser, ui-testing

I am trying to do my web application cross browser testing using batch scripting. I cannot use crossbrowser testing websites as my application runs on internal server.

For now, I am able to open the URLs on different browsers but the login blocks it to be fully automated. So I need to login manually with credentials and then the URL opens. Here is my code.

```
@echo off
echo Which URL would you like to open?
set /p var= 
start "Internet Explorer" "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" %var%
start "Firefox" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" %var%
start "Chrome.exe" %var%
exit
```

Please let me know to automate the login using batch script. Or is there any better way to do this process.

Comment: how the login forms look like? Are they pop-ups or they are part of the page? Have you considered to use selenium?

Comment: Hi @npocmaka. it is a basic login and is part of the page. Although I have considered selenium for long term plan, but for now I thought of using this simple way of batch scripting.